# Rokoko Retargeting from Plask.ai scatters pieces of my mesh

Tags: rigging

[image: You can see here the problem is that it sends a lot of the smaller disparate pieces of the mesh outward but they’re all still parented to the armature.]File is here: https://gofile.io/d/wfwyus

Not sure if this has to do with the mesh I’m retargeting to or from but once the retargeting is complete, a lot of pieces of my mesh get scattered all over the place while still being connected to the bones of my rig. Not sure if It’s because everything needs to be at origin or what. I tried aligning the bone roll but that does not seem to have done anything. Quite new to Rokoko and Plask so I’m sure I’m just doing something wrong but would love to figure out how avoid it so I can get this workflow into place.